# Parsing XML with Perl using XML::LibXML::XPathContext

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I have a perl subroutine that is intended to receive a basic xml document and use xpath expressions to gather specific information from the document. Here it is

```
    sub parseXml {
    my ($rawXml) = @_;
    print "Raw XML resonse:\n" . $rawXml . "\n";

    # Set up the XPath search.
    my $xp = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new;
    my $node = $xp->getContextNode;
    $xp->setContextNode($node);

    # Extract a list apiece of ids, whos, and whats.
    my @ids = $xp->findnodes('//object/void[@property="id"]/int');
    my @whos = $xp->findnodes('//object/void[@property="who"]/string');
    my @whats = $xp->findnodes('//object/void[@property="what"]/string');

    # Iterate over the arrays to print the data.
    my $it = each_array(@ids, @whos, @whats);
    while (my ($id, $who, $what) = $it->()) {
    print sprintf("%2d: ", $id->string_value) . 
        $who->string_value . " -> '" . 
        $what->string_value . "'\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the script, I get an error that says:

XPathContext: lost current node at ... line 83

What have I done wrong? I am VERY new to perl.

Comment: Which one is line 83?

Comment: Seems my guess on `getContextNode` was right. ;)

Comment: It sure was.  getContextNode was just in there to try some other solution that didn't work.  Your solution, Jens, was right, as-is. Thanks again for your help.  Robin, I believe line 83 was my $xp = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not parsing the input XML at any point. Given `$rawXml` is a string, make sure to do so by using

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $rawXml);
my $xp = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
```

My guess is line 83 is `my $node = $xp->getContextNode;`, which fails as the document is currently empty. You shouldn't need it anyway, together with the following line.

Comment: You are a blessing.  Thank you.  This is the answer and I will be happy to mark it as such.  Thanks again.  I hope this helps others out there as well.  And thanks to getting to me so quickly.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Alternatively, `$xpc->findnodes($xpath, $doc);`